# ffmpeg - concatenate files while space constrained

Tags: ffmpeg, windows, storage, concatenation

Let's say i have a 2 TB drive. If i want to use ffmpeg to concatenate two files, they cannot be larger than 1 TB in total, otherwise I won't have enough storage space to save the output file.

Is it possible for ffmpeg (or, perhaps, another tool) to concatenate two videos while also removing parts of the source files on the fly, allowing me to concatenate larger files? The files in questions will be encoded with the ffv1 codec and saved as mkv, although I'm fine with trying different containers.

Would saving files in smaller chunks to begin with be the only solution?